# Hacer click en un elemento y que esto haga visible uno e invisible otro

Tags: javascript

Mi intención (no sé si es loca o innecesaria pero es la idea) es la siguiente:

tengo un form ¡ de contacto (.form1) con tres opciones (cada una con su div, a la vez contenidas en 1 div (.form1)), las 2 primeras van a un link externo pero la 3 al hacer clic sobre ella debería hacer visible un (.form2) que es rellenable, de forma que al hacerse visible el (.form2) el (.form1) debe ocultarse.... ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Ojo: en el main.js las primeras 13 líneas incluyen variables, onload y listener de otras funciones que tengo + más todo lo relacionado con las funciones que estoy intentando lograr, lo he dejado para que tengan en cuenta que tengo esas otras en funcionamiento.

```js
var change0;
var change1;
var activating;

window.onload=changeLogo0;
window.onload=changeLogo1;
window.onload=activateform2;

addEventListener("load", () => {
    changeLogo0();
    changeLogo1();
    activateform2();
});


function activateform2() {
    activating=document.getElementById("emailOn");
    activating.addEventListener("click",functionVisible,false);
}

function makeVisible() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("form1").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementsByClassName("form2").style.visibility="visible";
}
```

```css
.contentContact{
    padding: 0.625rem;
    margin: -18rem 9rem 0 14rem;
    display: flex;
}

.options-form p{
    padding: 0rem 0.3rem 0rem 0.8rem;
} 

.contentContact .container-text{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    padding-right: 3rem;
}

.container-form{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    min-height:27.2rem;
    border-left: 0.1rem solid #39296650;
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.3rem #39296650;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

.top-form{
    background: #392966;
    border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0rem 0rem;
    padding: 0.8rem 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.8rem;
}

.form1, .form2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.form1{
    visibility: visible;
} 

.form2{
    margin-top: 6rem;
    visibility: hidden;
} 

.options-form1, .options-form2, .options-form3, .options-form4{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.250);
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    min-height:5rem;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    margin: 1rem 0.3rem 0rem 0.3rem;
}

.options-form1 a, .options-form2 a{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 18.5%;
    margin-top: -0.5rem;
}

input, textarea{
    margin-right: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.250);
    min-height: 1rem;
    border: none;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    color: #595661af;
}

textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 3rem;
}

#send, #send:visited{
    margin: 0.8rem 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.8rem;
    min-height: 2rem;
    min-width: 6rem;  
    background: #392966;
    color: #d6d3de;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#send:hover{
    background: #d25812;
    color: #d6d3de;
}

#send:active{
    background: #d25812;
    color: #d6d3de;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#option-checkbox{
    margin: 0.8rem 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
        <div class="container-form">
            <div class="form1">
                <div class="top-form">
                    <h4><strong>¡Let’s talk about it!</strong></h4>   
                </div>
                <p id="description">Elige la modalidad que mejor se adapte a ti:</p>

                <div class="options-form1">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank" id="link"></a>
                    <p><strong>Llamada</strong></p>
                    <p>Por teléfono - 15 min</p>
                </div>

                <div class="options-form2">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank" id="link"></a>
                    <p><strong>Online</strong></p>
                    <p>Vía Google Meet - 30 min</p>
                </div>

                <div class="options-form3" id="emailOn">
                    <p><strong>Email</strong></p>
                    <p>Haz clic aqui para redactar y enviar</p>
                </div> 
            </div>

            <div class="form2" id="emailSend">
                <div class="options-form4">
                    <p><strong><label for="user">Nombre:</label></strong></p>
                    <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
                    
                    <p><strong><label for="email">Email:</label></strong></p>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="">
                    
                    <p><strong>Mensaje</strong></p>
                    <textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="100">  Escribir aqui</textarea><br>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="option-checkbox3" id="option-checkbox" value="checkbox">
                    <label><i>He leído y acepto la política de privacidad y aviso legal*</i></label><br>

                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="send"><br>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

---

Es decir, así:

```js
function makeVisible() {
    document.querySelector(".form1").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector(".form2").classList.add("visible");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez te funcione de otra forma.

Al final del CSS, coloca dos clases así:

```
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Y en el JavaScript, no coloques los estilos con style.visibility, sino, a los form, colocales la clase respectiva para hacerlo o visible o esconderlo, por ejemplo:

```
function makeVisible() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("form1").classList.add="hidden";
    document.getElementsByClassName("form2").classList.add="visible";
}
```

Avisame si te funcionó, un saludo!

Comment: Hola Jonathan, no funciona :(

Comment: Perdona, tuve un error en mi respuesta, ya que add es un metodo, debería colocarse así: document.getElementsByClassName("form1").classList.add("hidden").

Comment: Otro problema puede ser que al usar getElementsByClassname, estas llamando a un grupo de elementos con la clase "form1", porque este metodo retorna un elemento parecido a un array. Intentalo mejor con document.querySelector('.form') y en este caso si debes colocar el punto al inicio del nombre de la clase

Comment: @JonathanGarcía, edita tu respuesta para agregar la opción con `querySelector()`, casi seguro que eso resuelve el problema.

Comment: @JonathanGarcía Sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: Ya me funciona, los = estaban de más @Jo

Answer (score 1):

Es un caso habitual que dos elementos "intercambian" su estado en la interfaz, ya sea si se muestran o no, si están des-habilitados, etc.

Lo más sencillo es definir una clase CSS que oculte un elemento en caso de que la tenga, p.e.

```
.none {
    display: none;
}
```

Y una función en JS que intercambie esta clase entre dos elementos dados:

```
function toggleClassName(nodeOne, nodeTwo, className = 'none') // void
{
    nodeOne.classList.remove(className);
    nodeOne.classList.add(className);
}
```

Esta función permite intercambiar otras clases CSS, por defecto, usa la indicada.

Ahora, llamar a esta función muestra un elemento y oculta otro, según el orden en que se pasan a la misma.
Por ejemplo, tengo dos botones, solo uno se muestra cada vez. Por supuesto, la película empieza con uno oculto, por tanto, tendrá la clase `none`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        function toggleClassName(nodeOne, nodeTwo, className = 'none') // void
        {
            nodeOne.classList.remove(className);
            nodeTwo.classList.add(className);
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        .center-content {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .none {
            display: none;
        }
        .pad-2 {
            padding: 2%;
        }
        .top-10 {
            margin-top: 10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center-content top-10">
        <button type="button" class="pad-2" id="buttonOne">
            Boton 1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="pad-2 none" id="buttonTwo">
            Boton 2
        </button>
    </div>

    <script>
        const buttonOne = document.querySelector('button#buttonOne');
        const buttonTwo = document.querySelector('button#buttonTwo');

        buttonOne.onclick = () => {
            toggleClassName(buttonTwo, buttonOne);
        }
        buttonTwo.onclick = () => {
            toggleClassName(buttonOne, buttonTwo);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```